# Contracted Employee never signed contract or have seen it

Tags: job-change

I work for a university in Utah.  I was hired in 2019 and supposedly I am under contract, however I have never signed a contract or received a copy of it.  My job was continued in 2020 however again I never signed anything for 2020-2021, or even said I was coming back or received anything, they just assumed I was back for 2020-2021.  I am looking at changing careers and a really good job came up in my area however I am wondering if I am still "stuck" with my contract until it expires in June or can I leave my employer with proper notice without legal recourse from my current employer saying I broke contract?

Comment: Ummm... why don't you just ask for a copy of the contract?

Comment: I agree with Joe. Ask them for a copy of your contract (and possibly a copy of the employee manual if the contract refers to it).

Comment: Be aware that asking for a copy of a contract might tip your hand that you are looking at ways to end it, or at least raise questions about why you want it.

Comment: @spuck That depends on how OP would ask for the contract. He could use the end of the year as an excuse and claim that when sorting through his paper work he noticed he doesn't have a copy. Just make it sound like a general request.

Comment: I'm assuming that not having signed a contract is a foul up by the HR department at the university. If the OP is looking for a new job for which he doesn't yet have a formal offer, then asking the university about his contract may result in him having to sign one to stay employed. That could potentially lock him in.

Answer (score 6):

You should email your manager and ask for copy of your contract. perhaps they will send you to someone in HR office. University systems are usually pretty well-staffed in bureaucracy.

You should contact a lawyer if anything in contract in unclear.

That being said, Utah is [at-will employment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-will_employment) state, which generally (IANAL) means that you can quit your job at any moment.

Answer (score 2):

First things first... I am not a lawyer (IANAL)

I expect that "contract employee" **in this instance** simply means that you don't get

- benefits
- chance of tenure
- holidays
- paid/sick leave

i.e. you aren't an "employee" at that university...  and you certainly aren't a *tenure track* employee.

If you didn't sign anything, then you likely aren't bound by a contract (remember IANAL).
There may be a "contract" at that university stating how such 'contract employees' are paid, and other work duties and expectations.

It would be worth asking about this contract - I'd expect you can do so anonymously, and have someone they don't know pick up a copy of it for you.
There may be expectations within it they expect you to follow (like what notice *they say* you owe them).  Note that while I suspect those aren't legal obligations of yours, following them prevents you from burning a bridge you may need later (in case you haven't noticed yet, this is a very small world sometimes).

For what it is worth, I always advise people to work a reasonable notice.
You'll have to decide if you want to do that, and what that would look like if you do.

Comment: You can't ask about a contract for a specific person anonymously. Contracts also change, so even if the contract is generic, you'd need not the current version but rather the version that was in effect at the time the OP was employed. As I mentioned in a comment on the question, I worry that asking about the contract would force HR to correct their mistake and get a contract signed or terminate the employment.

Comment: @MaxW You may be correct, IANAL - and employment law is a curious thing that varies by state and can vary by employer type (such as university). The employee is asking about leaving though... if it were me I'd ask to get a copy of the contract so I could exit gracefully (in their eyes - don't want to burn a bridge if you don't have to).